# How to run squid in bridge mode

Tags: iptables, squid, dpdk

I have two Ethernet interfaces in my pc eno1 and eno2, eno1 is bind to DPDK application and eno1 is connected to pc A with ip 192.168.1.10 via lan cable, and eno2 interface is still in control of linux kernel and is connected to pc B with ip 192.168.1.1 the DPDK application that bind port eno1 is also created a virtual port dtap0 that can pass data between kernel and user-sapce, there is a bridge between eno2 and and dtap0, ping is working between pc A and B now i want to run squid such that any http traffic coming through eno2 pass through squid then if not present in cache then it should go through the bridge, how to forward all http traffic from
Eno2 to squid

i have tried running squid in transparent mode with iptables but it doesn’t work
OS -rhel 8.2
Squid ver 4